different versions of libwebkit2gtk-4.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ and in /usr/local/lib/ : what to do?
I doscovered that the libwebkit2gtk-4.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ is 0.16.3 while the libwebkit2gtk-4.1 in /usr/local/lib/ is 0.12.6 :
raphy@raohy:~/wxWidgets/build-gtk/samples/webview$ ldd webview | grep -i webkit
libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so.0 (0x0000756e6bc00000)

raphy@raohy:~$ ls -lah /usr/local/lib | grep -i libwebkit
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root    22 dic 15  2023 libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so -> libwebkit2gtk-
4.1.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root    27 lug 28 17:53 libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so.0 -> libwebkit2gtk-
4.1.so.0.12.6
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  3,5G dic 26  2023 libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so.0.12.6

But :
raphy@raohy:~$ cd /usr/local/lib && dpkg -S libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so
libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so.0
libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.1.so.0.16.3

OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Shouldn't be the same, has libwebkit2gtk-4.1 been installed through the ubuntu repository?
What would you suggest me to do?

Things in /usr/local are not distro- but manually installed.
So, if you have anything in there, you must have installed it there manually; if the rest of the system moved on in versions, it's your "duty" to rebuild the things in /usr/local.
In other words: I don't know what you did install manually (without using apt) into /usr/local, but that's the thing you shouldn't have and need updating,

Thanks Marcus. I discovered that is one of the issues
